# Symlinking all dot-files and -directories

Tags: bash, zsh, symlink, dot-files

Say I have a folder `~/dot` containing some files and directories, such as
`zshrc`, `Xresources`, and `emacs.d`.  How do I create symlinks to all of those in `~`, but such that the symlinks begin with a dot (`.zshrc` &c.)?

And how would I remove all already existing symlinks that would have been created by the answer to the first question?  (I.e. how would I uninstall my dotfiles.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**creating the symlinks**

```
cd ~/dot
for file in *; do
    ln -sf dot/"$file" ~/."$file"
done
```

**deleting the symlinks**

```
cd
for dotfile in .*; do
    test -L || continue
    target="$(readlink "$dotfile")"
    [[ $target =~ ^dot/ ]] && echo rm "$dotfile"
done
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to do as in the first, but test if `~/."$file` is a symlink before unlinking?

Comment: @Toothrot That would be an option if you can be sure that files in `dot` are neither deleted nor renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc:
(cd && zmv -sL -v 'dot/(*)' '.$1')
```

To remove them:

```
(cd && files=(dot/*(:t)) && rm -vf -- .$^files(N@))
```

(remove the `-v` for verbose if your `rm` implementation doesn't support it)

For each `dot/foo` file, that removes `.foo` if it's a symlink (whether it points to to `dot/foo` or not). Alternatively, you could do:

```
rm .*(@e'<[[ $REPLY -ef dot/${REPLY#.} ]]>')
```

That is remove the `.foo` symlinks if it's the same file (after symlink resolution) as `old/foo`.